# request specs with devise

Tags: rspec, devise, capybara, omniauth

This should be fairly easy to answer, I hope. I did look around and couldn't find the answer even though it may be something straight-forward.

When running my spec and

```
visit correspondences_path
```

I get

```
Failure/Error: visit '/correspondences'
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   No route matches {:controller=>"users/omniauth_callbacks", :action=>"passthru", :provider=>:facebook}
 # ./app/views/layouts/_navigation.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts__navigation_html_erb___642964846_100119950'
```

Obviously I got omniauth buttons on my navbar, though everything works fine in the browser. The page is only viewable if the user is authenticated by Devise:

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_correspondences, correspondences_count: 1)
```

then I,

```
sign_in_as_a_valid_user(user)
```

which is a helper I defined in spec/support...so everything should be working, I thought.

If I, instead

```
get correspondences_path
```

All I get is a doctype declaration (when print page.html) on the page and any other assertions pass even though they shouldn't be.

I'm vague because I'm convinced I'm doing something stupid here and somebody will point it out to me quickly without having to post all my code which isn't very interesting.
My gratitude in advance.

routes are simple:

```
authenticated :user do
  root :to => 'correspondences#index'
end

root :to => 'home#index'

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
resources :users, :only => [:show, :index]

resources :correspondences
resources :recipients
```

support/request_macros.rb

```
module ValidUserRequestHelper
  def sign_in_as_a_valid_user(user)
    post_via_redirect user_session_path, 'user[email]' => user.email, 'user[password]' => user.password
  end
```

and in spec_helper.rb

```
...
config.include ValidUserRequestHelper, :type => :request
...
end
```

so in the spec:

```
...
it "shold display a users corresponces" do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_correspondences, correspondences_count: 1)
  sign_in_as_a_valid_user(user)
  visit correspondences_path
  page.all('.correspondences').count == 3 #never gets here
end
```

Frustrating... I can't understand why its even trying the link to the facebook omniauth when I'm not testing that...

Comment: Can you paste your `routes.rb`? Maybe you need to pass something into your `correspondences_path` like `correspondences_path(user)` or something else.

Comment: So, I finally figured it out..pretty dumb: in devise.rb, for facebook I specified my facebook SECRET keys for production and development and there was nothing for test.... wah, wah, wah

Comment: Thanks for this - you should submit and accept this as the answer... Some people might miss it down here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the devise config line on user.rb didn't match the auth provider name. I was trying to `=link_to "login using Twitter", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter)` and the configuration on `user.rb` read `devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:twiter]` (notice I was missing a 't')